# Programmatically determining pagination limit when inserting element of unknown height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent element of height 300 that I am inserting li element into. The li elements are being filled with strings of arbitrary length which causes the parent li elements to vary in height. The issue is that sometimes the heights of the combined li elements exceeds the height of the parent element which causes them to overflow. I would like to detect overflow and then decrement the number of items per page until there is no overflow. However, I'm worried there will be performance issues performing these operations in the DOM.

Comment: what are you paginating ?  results from a db ?

Comment: Yes, so based off user input I'm fetching an array of string where the length of the array and the length of each string is unknown.

Comment: Its tricky to say the least, I think I would use a js mvc like angular so you can pool the results that don't "fit" in an array for re-use on the next page to improve efficiency, The only way i can think determining the max number of pages would be to store the height value of each record in the db,  
 so you know how much space they occupy calculate it from that, though it may not be practical to do that

Comment: honestly, i think i would try to alter the design to  accommodate for varying height of the ul/ol and save yourself a big headache

Comment: yes I agree, calculating and storing the height is an interesting suggestion though!

Comment: Rather than detecting if you go over, I would probably just loop through the initial insert and detect it then.  There will be a performance hit either way but depending on the number of `li` it shouldn't be too bad, probably not even noticeable.  If the total number of items is small enough it is probably more efficient to just pull them all from the db and do all the paging in the js.